# Understanding of Max Backup Index in log4j framework

Tags: java, file, log4j, outputstream

I will introduce to you a simple source example:

```
#Level
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, f

#Appender
log4j.appender.f = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.f.File = C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Test.txt

#File size
log4j.appender.f.MaxFileSize = 100KB
log4j.appender.f.MaxBackupIndex = 1
```

I understand the working of source and see that the output result will be "logger messages" written in file *Test.txt*. And when I have reached the max file size of *100KB* it will be created new file with name *Test.txt.1*

My simple issue is can I generate new file to be with name **Test1.txt** no *Test.txt.1*

Best regards,
D.Balamjiev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a custom `FileNamePattern`, using `%i` which is the index of the file :

```
#Appender
log4j.appender.f = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.f.File = C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Test.txt
log4j.appender.f.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\Test%i.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

That parameter is defining how many files will be kept after deleting from rollback policy:

the official [doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders/rolling-file.html) states:

> **maxBackupIndex**: Maximum number of backup files to keep.

in your case that will happen every time the loger file reaches the 100KB you defined...

Comment: Yes I understand that, but is it possible to manage the output file name?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *Berger* for the idea.

Here is my full working source

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, Roller

log4j.appender.Roller=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy.maxIndex=5
    log4j.appender.Roller.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.Roller.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize= 50000
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=D:\\Test\\Fixed.txt

log4j.appender.Roller.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Roller.layout.ConversionPattern = Date: %d{dd-MM-yyyy} Time: %d{HH:mm:ss} [Message is: %m] Other/%r [%t] %-5p %c %x/%n
```